# Map escape+s to save file in vim

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I want a shortcut to save the current file in Vim. I want to map escape+s to :w.
I tried

```
:map <esc-s> :w
```

but it doesnt work.

Comment: In case you weren't aware, this will obscure a vim function. `s` in normal mode deletes the character under the cursor and enters insert mode.

Comment: You are mixing two native vim commands to do the work of another native vim command. `:w` is better than `<Esc>s` because it doesn't force you to reach for the `<Esc>` key.

Comment: Marty: Well i didnt know you could do that with s. I have mapped <C-s> to :w now. Had to tweak the terminal for that though. 
romainl: I have escape mapped to my caps lock so its not a problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try,

```
:map <Esc>s :w
```

Or perhaps,

```
:map <Esc>s :w<CR>
```

`<CR>`, `<Enter>`, and `<Return>` are the keycodes for the return/enter key.

Comment: It is the least one. `:map <Esc>s :w<CR>`
Thank you Marty